# pthreads const string corruption

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

Using PHP7 RC7 and the latest dev build from pthreads: 3.1.0-dev on Ubuntu 3.13.0-66-generic

I've narrowed down a problem to a simple test case, that I'm getting with a const value that is not working as I expect.

The code below outputs: value:v

When it should be: value:|

The value of the const isnt changing, if I var_dump it, it is still a |, but when its concatenated with the string 'value:' it seems to take the first char of the string rather than the value of the const. I presume its some kind of memory leaking. My code? or maybe a bug?

Seems to only cause a problem if the string 'value:' is 6 chars or less and using the const. Above that, it seems fine.

If I make cacheRecord 'Threaded' then it does fix the problem, but I am then unable to remove/unset the array value later on as it is then immutable.

```
<?php

const FIELD_SEP = '|';

class cacheRecord
{
    public $field1;
    public $field2;
}

class cache extends Threaded
{
    public function run()
    {}
}

class socketThread extends Thread
{

    public function __construct($cache)
    {
        $this->cacheLogin = $cache;
    }

    public function run()
    {

        $cl = new cacheRecord;
        $cl->field1 = 'test123';
        $this->cacheLogin['myhash'] = $cl;

        $testString = FIELD_SEP.$cl->field1;

        echo 'value:'.FIELD_SEP."\n";

        unset($this->cacheLogin['myhash']);
    }

 }

$cache = new cache;

// Main

$socketThread = new socketThread($cache);
$socketThread->start();
$socketThread->join();
```

Comment: @JoeWatkins: Why not make this an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have found a bug in that release of pthreads, it is fixed in v3.1.1

Comment: Fantastic, yep.. that fixed it. Thanks Joe.